# insert php foreach into jquery append function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, foreach, append

In my form I have a button which when clicked appends a row of fields to be filled out by the user.

One of these fields uses a foreach loop to get the select group options but I'm unsure of how to output that into the .append() call.

```
$(function() { $("button#add_billable").click(function(){ $("#billables").append("
<div class='row'>
  <div class='large-5 columns'>
    <label for='invoice_line'>Invoice Line</label><select name='invoice_billable[]'>
      <?php foreach ($pages->find('template=billable') as $billable) { ?>
      <option value='<?php echo $billable->id; ?>'>
        <?php echo $billable->title; ?>
      </option><?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='large-5 columns'>
    <label for='line_value'>Value</label><input name='line_value[]' type='text' value='' />
  </div>
  <div class='large-1 columns'>
    <button class='delete tiny secondary'>-</button>
  </div>
</div>"); }); });
```

Could anyone give me a pointer? Thank you.

Comment: removed php tag. This is a javascript/jquery question

Comment: @STTLCU read the code better, it has PHP in it

Comment: oh, i see it. well, not a nice readable code, isn't it?

Comment: acutally your method is not that bad, another way could be to `json_encode` your option array and put it into a javascript variable, and then iterator through that with javascript, it makes the code cleaner, but doenst enhance performance

Comment: OP why don't you `display:none` the row when outputten and show it when you click the button?

Comment: Server-side code executes before client-side code...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @x4rf41 how would I go about that? Corpses, each line gets added as per the need for a new line in the invoice. pmandell, the PHP code should already be valid then so just needs inserting into js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP needs to write the data to a JSON object or Javascript variable, or something that Javascript can read.

Then in your click event, before your insert your HTML, you need to build up your select html based on the data that was written to the page

Comment: Thank you James. Do you have any pointers, or where to read up to achieve this?

Comment: I don't get involved in PHP much, so this may not be perfect, but you can write a PHP array straight to a JSON object, something like:

$objJSON = json_encode($phpArray);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var myJSON = ' . $objJSON . ';</script>

Comment: Then use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ to iterate through the data, either build up a string or create a HTML object
$.each(myJSON, function() {

});

Comment: Thank you, James. I've yet to get my version working but have no doubt this is the most helpful answer.